# How to keep 2 git repositories in sync automatically

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

Having 2 servers which should be in sync with eachothers at all times.

As someone pushes something to the repository of server A, the repository on server B should be updated automatically, depending what server is the master/slave.

Both servers are not on the same machine.

Is this possible without having to run additional manual commands every update? (git fetch etc.) Or do you advise a different mechanism?

Comment: Can the users push to both servers? Or is this a backup / failover scenario?

Comment: You can use ``cron`` or ``hooks``.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes, it is a backup / failover scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `post-receive` or `update` [Git Hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to push between repositories.

Comment: So just dropping my git commands in `.git/hooks/post-commit` to push, what to do for server B to commit?

Comment: You shouldn't need to commit anything - pushing references (likely with `--all`) should be sufficient.