# What is the proper way to keep 2 dependent repositories in sync?

Tags: git, github

I have 2 projects, each in its own Git repository.

Project A represents our Client Application.

Project B represents our Server.

I need to perform a git bisect on Project A, but when I go back more than a week the application will no longer run because Project B (which is a dependency for Project A) is out of date. I am forced to manually go through the commits of Project B until I can find a commit which the Project A meshes well with.

What is the proper way to keep 2 dependent repositories in sync? We can't increment the version on every single commit because we are committing to each project several times a day. I wish there was some form of 'commit stamp'; where when you commit, it is automatically noted the most recent commits of the dependent repositories.

Note:

There is another similar question about keep repositories in sync. [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596503/how-to-keep-2-git-repositories-in-sync-automatically) is referring to keeping 2 repositories of the same data in sync as where I am referring to keeping 2 different repositories where each represents a different project in sync.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to put a script like the following in project A:

```
project_a_date=`git log -1 --format=%cd --date=raw`
cd /path/to/project_b
project_b_hash=`git log --min-age=$project_a_date -1 --pretty=format:'%H'`
git checkout $project_b_hash
```

This will take the date of the currently checked out commit in project A, and checkout the corresponding commit in project B. The only catch is that you need to know the local path to project b in either absolute terms, or relative to project B.